# Resolution specific subfolders of res directory crash the app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-resources, android-resolution

I have created a Phone & Tablet app for android and have the generic layout folder populated with the layouts, I then created two additional folders in the res directory with the suffix -sw600dp & -sw720dp and it is not working and the app is crashing every time no matter what I try. Can someone please give me some other options.

Log Cat Error:

```
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at za.co.astroweb.watsonline.wats_online_fragment$getBlogPosts.onPostExecute(wats_online_fragment.java:173)
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at za.co.astroweb.watsonline.wats_online_fragment$getBlogPosts.onPostExecute(wats_online_fragment.java:1)
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-01 02:34:23.567: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post the logcat output?

Comment: Added Log Cat error message to the original question.

Comment: Did you actually *read* the error log that you posted? The error has no relation to your resource folders.

Comment: Sorry that was an earlier error that I solved the real error that I don't know how to solve it added in the original question, thanks